# How can I replace the start of each string in a list in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a list of strings in CMake and want to replace the first two characters of each string with "00".

I have tried

```
set(THINGS ABCD DEFG HIJK)
list(TRANSFORM THINGS REPLACE "^.." "00" OUTPUT_VARIABLE MANGLED_THINGS)
message(SEND_ERROR "Mangled: ${MANGLED_THINGS}")
```

But I get the result

```
Mangled: 0000;0000;0000
```

I expected

```
Mangled: 00CD;00FG;00JK
```

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you showed in your answer post, you can do

> ```
> set(THINGS ABCD DEFG HIJK)
> list(TRANSFORM THINGS REPLACE "^..(.*)" "00\\1" OUTPUT_VARIABLE  MANGLED_THINGS)
> message(SEND_ERROR "Mangled: ${MANGLED_THINGS}")
> ```

Another way is to use a `foreach` loop and use `list(GET)`, then either `string(REPLACE)` or `string(SUBSTRING)`, and then `list(APPEND)` to a new list, but I think yours is nicer in being more concise.

Since you're curious about why the weird behaviour you're observing is occurring:

#### Shoddy Detective Work

I suspect the reason for the behaviour you're observing to be an implementation bug in CMake.

Just taking a look at the docs and seeing your problem, alarm bells were already ringing in my head. [The docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#transform) state:

> `REPLACE`: Match the regular expression as many times as possible and substitute the replacement expression for the match for each element of the list (Same semantic as `REGEX REPLACE` from [string()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html) command).

Now notice that if you set an *odd* number of characters in your input with your `TRANSFORM`, the very last character is not change into a zero, but the rest *are*. Now try switching your regex to replace some `N` number of characters, and try with inputs that are length `a*N+b`, and observe that the last `b` characters are the only ones that "survive".

So the hypothesis is: when CMake tries to execute a regex more times, it starts from after what it last matched, and forgets to take into consideration any anchor constraints like `^`. Taking a look at [the code in cmStringReplaceHelper.cxx](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmStringReplaceHelper.cxx), I find it suspect:

```cpp
bool cmStringReplaceHelper::Replace(const std::string& input,
                                    std::string& output)
{
  output.clear();

  // Scan through the input for all matches.
  std::string::size_type base = 0;
  while (this->RegularExpression.find(input.c_str() + base)) {
  ...
```

There doesn't seem to be any info to tell `RegularExpression.find` about the fact that there was previous content to the input string it's being passed, which would be pertinent to it knowing whether what it's given is really the start of the input.

I created an issue ticket: [Multiple/"global" regex matching matches starting anchor (^) patterns for non-first matches #24807](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24807).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is one way to do it, but I don't understand why the original replace inserts "0000" and not just "00".

```
set(THINGS ABCD DEFG HIJK)
list(TRANSFORM THINGS REPLACE "^..(.*)" "00\\1" OUTPUT_VARIABLE MANGLED_THINGS)
message(SEND_ERROR "Mangled: ${MANGLED_THINGS}")
```